# Where do I find the python source code/documentation for the selenium ActionBuilder class?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to rewrite the selenium [ActionChains class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.html#ActionChains) and noticed that it uses the ActionBuilder class. Browsing the python documentation and the internet I was only able to find a documentation for the [ruby](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html) and [c#](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/ActionBuilder.cs) implementation of the ActionBuilder class and not one for python. Does it simply not exist? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source code in the selenium github repository. But I don't know if there are any documentation for `ActionBuilder` class exists or not.

Here is the link to `action_builder.py` file.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial documentation, maybe it could help:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

Comment: That certainly helps. Thank you!